# Postgres: How to make NULL friendly MIN filtering in Having clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, having, having-clause

`audit_table` might contain repeated `userId`.

We have following SQL query

```
SELECT userId FROM audit_table
GROUP BY userId 
HAVING MIN(updatedDate) > ?;
```

`updatedDate` field might be null and for case when all rows in `audit_table` for concrete `userId` contains only nulls I don't see these rows but I want.
Is there way to acheve it ?

Comment: `or HAVING MIN(updatedDate) is null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is an explicit comparison:

```
SELECT userId FROM audit_table
GROUP BY userId 
HAVING MIN(updatedDate) > ? OR MIN(updatedDate) IS NULL;
```

Another method is to count the `updatedDates` that are less than `?` or `NULL`:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE updatedDate <= ?) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please add performance notes for these approaches ?

P.S. in my original case I need to select only one userId

Comment: @gstackoverflow . . . The two should be pretty similar from a performance perspective, but `filter` might be a wee bit faster.  If you only want one user id, ask a new question.  There might be other approaches.  Be sure to include the number of rows that would match and the sizes of the tables.