# Postgres: How to make NULL friendly MIN filtering in Having clause to select exactly one row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by, having

According Gordon Linoff advice I've created a new followup question for [Postgres: How to make NULL friendly MIN filtering in Having clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68619941/postgres-how-to-make-null-friendly-min-filtering-in-having-clause/68620167?noredirect=1#comment121273169_68620167)

```
SELECT userId FROM audit_table
GROUP BY userId 
HAVING MIN(updatedDate) > ? OR MIN(updatedDate) IS NULL;
ORDER BY userId 
LIMIT 1
```

Is there way to make this quesry more performant in POSTGRES ?

Comment: Can you add the indexes and the `explain analyse` to your post?

Comment: @Jim Jones I have index for updatedDate

Comment: Which index? Please add the query plan.

Comment: Convert the `OR` to a `UNION`; Index by updatedDate; Limit each subquery and limit the UNION.

Comment: Do you have a separate table of users?  How large is `audit_table`?  What indexes are available?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff audit_table contains hundreds millions of rows. There are only one index by updatedDate. Yes - there are separated table for users

Comment: @The Impaler could you please be a bit more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about performance you can:

- Convert the OR to a UNION ALL.
- Index by `updatedDate`.
- Limit each subquery, and
- limit the UNION ALL.

For example you can add the index (and some data):

```
create table audit_table (
  userId int,
  updatedDate date
);

insert into audit_table (userId, updatedDate) values
  (123, '2021-02-03'),
  (456, '2021-04-12'),
  (789, '2021-01-22'),
  (477, null);

create index ix1 on audit_table (updatedDate nulls last, userId);
```

Then the query will use the index:

```
select *
from (
  (
  select userId, updatedDate
  from audit_table
  order by updatedDate nulls last
  limit 1
  )
 union all
  (
  select userId, updatedDate
  from audit_table
  where updatedDate is null
  limit 1
  )
) x
order by updatedDate nulls last
limit 1
```

Result:

```
 userid  updateddate
 ------- -----------
 789     2021-01-22
```

The query above will use indexes when there is a significant number of rows. If the table only has a few hundred rows, the engine may end up ignoring the index and will read the whole table instead.

**NOTE**: If both a null and not null rows are found you can choose which one to prioritize. In the previous to last line `nulls first` will prioritize the null row, while `nulls last` will prioritize the non-null one.

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/knTufwqWjzhPWeo2omhG9h/0).